gnome tweaks cursor does not appl to certain apps such as discord or brave
I have been using linux for over a week and I have downloaded a program called gnome tweaks to customize my computer's appearance. But it doesn't work on some of the programs. For example when I changed my cursor's look it didnt apply on some programs such as discord or brave. How can I solve this issue.Ubuntu 24.04

Several issues are here. 1. What is the version of Ubuntu you are using? Please Edit the question and add this info. 2. The Gnome tweaks affects the OS not the apps. Yo would need to edit each app with some kind of program to do that.
